# Re-write a json file to add missing data values with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to re-write a json file to add missing data values. but i cant seem to get the code to re-write the data on the json file. Here is the code to fill in missing data:

```
import pandas as pd
import json 



data_df = pd.read_json("Data_test.json")

#replacing empty strings with nan
df2 = data_df.mask(data_df == "")

#filling the nan with data from above. 
df2["Food_cat"].fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True,)
```

"Data_test.json" is the file with the list of dictionary and I am trying to either edit this json file or create a new one with the filled in data that was missing.

I have tried using

```
with open('complete_data', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(df2, f)
```

but it does not seem to work. is there a way to edit the current data or create a new json file with the completed data?

[this is the original data, I would like to keep this format.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yZQA.png)

Comment: Have you tried `df.to_json
(location_to_save)`

Comment: "but it does not seem to work" - what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Also you might want to add the file extension when writing `with open("complete_data.json", "w")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```py
import pandas as pd
import json 



data_df = pd.read_json("Data_test.json")

#replacing empty strings with nan
df2 = data_df.mask(data_df == "")

#filling the nan with data from above. 
df2["Food_cat"].fillna(method="ffill", inplace=True,)

df2.to_json('path_of_file.json')
```

Tell me if it works.

Comment: It works! Thanks! The layout is changed as my original data is a list of dictionary, when i run the code above it changes to dictionary, is there a way to keep it as list of dictionary?

Comment: I added a picture of the original data i wanted to keep that format.

Comment: could you rewrite the original format content?

Comment: I would like to keep it in the original format content.